# Apacite and multibbl: how use them together?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite

I'm now able to create 2 bibliography with this code, in my `bibltest.tex` file, like this:

```
latex bibltest.tex
bibtex biblio1
bibtex biblio2
pdflatex bibltest.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{biblio1}
\newbibliography{biblio2}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{biblio1}{plain}
\bibliography{biblio1}{bib1}{My bibliography 1}
\nocite{biblio2}{*}
\bibliographystyle{biblio2}{plain}
\bibliography{biblio2}{bib2}{My bibliography 2}

\end{document}
```

But I doesn't word if I want apacite package. What could I do ?  And what can I do to make a citation, like `\cite{aa}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{biblio1}
\newbibliography{biblio2}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{biblio1}{apacite}
\bibliography{biblio1}{bib1}{My bibliography 1}
\nocite{biblio2}{*}
\bibliographystyle{biblio2}{apacite}
\bibliography{biblio2}{bib2}{My bibliography 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I don't think `multibbl` is compatible with any bibliography package, since it is a simple redefinition of the core `\cite` commands. You might want to look instead at `multibib`, which is compatible with `natbib`, and load the `apacite` package with the `natbibapa` option. Alternatively, `biblatex` is excellent at this sort of thing, and `biblatex-apa` supports the APA format.